# Debian and active directory authentication

Tags: active-directory, debian, nsswitch.conf

I'm trying to link a debian server authentication to active directory.
I followed this tutorial: http://wiki.debian.org/Authenticating_Linux_With_Active_Directory but I'm stuck on the

```
getent passwd
```

Because this doesn't list all AD users but only locals.
This is my nsswitch.conf:

```
passwd:         files winbind
group:          files winbind
shadow:         files winbind
```

And I'm sure it is well connected to AD becuse this:

```
wbinfo -u
```

Lists all AD users.
What have I missed?

Comment: Check enum user directives in smb.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not running `getent passwd` as root, this is expected behaviour in most cases as as a standard user should not get access to the user list. Knowing the username of a user you could check via

```
$ getent passwd <username>
```

too. This should be possible for root and non-root users.

If this does not work, you should take a look at the logs:

- /var/log/krb5.log
- /var/log/auth.log
- /var/log/samba/*